# Xamarin iOS storyboard stretches objects

Tags: ios, xamarin, storyboard, widget

I have started a new iOS project in xamarin, and for some reason, when i drag a widget from toolbox onto a view, it just stretches the widget to fit the whole view and i cant do anything about it...

See attached: textview example with its properties[textview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNmEU.jpg)

[textview properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVps6.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Ok it seems that i deleted the View widget and thats why every other item that i dragged onto an "empty" viewcontroller, was stretched to match the height and width...

i guess there must be a View widget on which all other widgets can me placed.